# Как написать программу для разных операционных систем?

Tags: java, swing

Написал программу на java 1.8
Использую swing.
Работаю под Windows
Если программу запустить на Linux оказывается, что толщина рамок Frame в Linux отличается от толщины рамки в Windows.
Из-за этого всё изображение во Frame справа и внизу на несколько пикселей не влезает.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Дополнение:
  Вы посоветовали использовать pack(), вот я написал такой вариант

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainWindow extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage background;
    private MainWindow() throws IOException {
            load();
            setLayout(null);
            setBounds(0,0,576,676);
            JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();
            myLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(background));
            myLabel.setBounds(0,0,576,676);
            add(myLabel);

            JFrame win = new JFrame();
            win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            win.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,300));
            //win.setLayout(null);
            win.add(this);
            win.pack();
            win.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void load(){
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Pole3.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException ez){}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

Окно не растягивается, что я сделал не так?  В чём ошибка?

Comment: >java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode) ---- Вот такая версия установлена

Comment: А шрифты разве нельзя вставить прямо в программу? Я думал, что в папку с программой скопирую нужные шрифты и буду использовать.

Comment: Как использовать линии вместо рамок? У Frame разве можно выключить рамки?

Comment: Я бы советовал вам перейти на **JavaFx**. Как по мне, он более удобен и современен для разработки UI приложений на Java. Ещё из полезных плюшек у него есть ScreenBuider - удобый конструктор форм, да и он воспитает у вас любовь к паттернам.
Здесь есть неплохое вступление в JavaFx: https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/javafx

Comment: А есть более подробное описание на русском?

Comment: Прошу прощения, для ответа в комментариях у меня недостаточно репутации, потому отвечу здесь. Конечно, в рунете тоже немало информации о **JavaFx**:
https://habr.com/ru/post/474292/
https://o7planning.org/ru/10623/javafx-tutorial-for-beginners

Answer (score 2):

Быстрое и простое решение: чтобы изменить размер окна учитывая содержимое - используйте метод [pack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) после того, как созданы все компоненты.

```
frame.pack();
```

Это приведет к изменению размеров окна учитывая рамки и будет работать на любой системе и с любыми настройками шрифтов, масштабирования и т.д.

Comment: Я исправил вопрос. Написал код в котором попытался использовать pack(). Подскажите, почему он не работает?